# Right aligned text in the same line

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, scaling

```
\documentclass[12pt] {article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\begin{document}
   \begin{enumerate}[1.]
    \item Qustion no 1.
    \begin{flushright}
        [Ans:\;0.168]
    \end{flushright}
    \mbox{[Hint:]}
    \item Qustion no 2.
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item sub question a?
        \item sub question b?\hspace*{\fill}\makebox[1in][l]{[Ans: (a)\;0.0357,\;(b)\;0.736]}
    \end{enumerate}
    \mbox{[Hint:]}
\end{document}
```

The first answer remains within the page margin but the second one exceeds the margin. `\begin{flushright}` provides more vertical space and `\hspace*{\fill}\makebox[1in][l]` doesn't keep text within mirgin. How to fix this?

Comment: What do you want? Something like `\item sub question b?\hfill [Ans: (a)\;0.0357,\;(b)\;0.736]`?

Comment: @wipet anything that suits for arbitrary length of `[Ans:...]` part.

Comment: Arbitrary length may not fit in single line. Moreover, including the text on the left. My first comment isn't a sufficient solution?

Comment: @wipet then perhaps in a new line. But if the vertical spaces among question, [Ans:] and [Hint;] are too much, it is not eye soothing. This happens with `\begin{flushright}` where the vertical spaces become too much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define the macro `\toright`:

```
\def\toright#1{\leavevmode\unskip\nobreak\hfill\penalty13 
               \null\nobreak\hskip1em plus1fill\hbox{#1}}
```

and then write

```
    \item sub question b? \toright {[Ans: (a)\;0.0357,\;(b)\;0.736]}
```

The `\toright {parameter}` must be the last object in the pragraph.

How it works: If the text fits to the single line then there is stretchable glue `\hfill` and `\hskip 1em plus1fill` which is more stretchable than the default glye from `\parfillskip`. So, `\parfillskip` gets zero width ad the mentioned glue is used. If the text doesn't fit t the single line, then it is broken at `\penalty13`. The `\hfill` fills the space in the first line and `\hskip 1em plus 1fill` fisll the space in the second line. It is protected by `\null` box because `\hskip` itself creates a glue which is discardable item.

Why there is `1em` in the `\hskip` parameter: we don't want to get a case where text at the left is directly followed by the text at the right without space. At least `1em space must be between them.

Comment: Although I don't need a long line, I tried with one. Unfortunately the line is not breaking. Rather it goes beyond to the right margin.

Comment: Did you mean the long text on the right side? Of course, it must be shorter than line size because it is in `\hbox`. When I mentioned "does not fit", I did mean the left side text plus right side text together.